# Google Bigquery - Create time series of number of active records

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, aggregate

I'm trying to create a timeseries in google bigquery SQL. My data is a series of time ranges covering the period of activity for that record. Here is an example:

```
Start                   End
2020-11-01 21:04:00 UTC 2020-11-02 07:15:00 UTC
2020-11-01 21:45:00 UTC 2020-11-02 04:00:00 UTC
2020-11-01 22:00:00 UTC 2020-11-02 09:48:00 UTC
2020-11-01 22:00:00 UTC 2020-11-02 06:00:00 UTC
```

I wish to create a new table to total the number of active records within a 15 minute block. "21:00:00" would for example be 21:00 to 21:14.59. My desired output for the above would be:

```
Period              Active_Records
2020-11-01 21:00:00 1
2020-11-01 21:15:00 1
2020-11-01 21:30:00 1
2020-11-01 21:45:00 2
2020-11-01 22:00:00 4
2020-11-01 22:15:00 4
```

etc until the end of the last active range.

I would also like to be able to generate this on the fly by querying a date range and having it return every 15 minute block in the range and how many active records there was in that period.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select ts as period, count(1) as Active_Records
from unnest((
  select generate_timestamp_array(timestamp_trunc(min(start), hour), max(`end`), interval 15 minute)
  from `project.dataset.table` 
)) ts 
join `project.dataset.table`
on not (`end` < ts or start > timestamp_add(ts, interval 15 * 60 - 1 second))
group by ts
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail! I've used many of your past answers to solve my problems in the past, so I appreciate you taking the time to help me with my issue. I have a few questions on this answer:
- What is the reason for wrapping the unnest content in double parenthesis?
- Can you please elaborate on the logic in the third last and second last lines of the SQL?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: to use a query as an expression, the query must be wrapped with additional parentheses

Comment: third last and second last lines - i combined them into one now - it is to make sure respective period counts all relevant rows - such that rows for which `end` is not less than start of period and `start` not greater than end of period